# How to solve "pg_dump server version mismatch error" when you find 4 different pg_dump binaries?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

Attempting to get the Postgresql database on my local machine, but I am getting this error:

```
pg_dump: error: server version: 14.5; pg_dump version: 12.8
pg_dump: error: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

Running this command:

```
find / -name pg_dump -type f 2>/dev/null
```

I found 4 different pg_dump versions on my end:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@15/15.1/bin/pg_dump
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@15/15.1/bin/pg_dump
/System/Volumes/Data/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/pg_dump
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/pg_dump
```

How can I change my pg_dump to the correct version?

I've tried to use `ln -s` to link the files to the correct version, and generally understanding what to do with little luck. An explanation to this problem would be greatly appreciated

Comment: 1) Determine whether you need and/or have databases running  in all those versions of Postgres.  With the idea that you will uninstall unneeded versions. 2) The error says `server version: 14.5`, but I don't see a 14 version of `pg_dump`. Where is the server you are trying to dump from located? 3) Read the *Notes* section here [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html). In particular the paragraph starting *Because pg_dump is used to transfer data  ...* for how to use `pg_dump` against different versions of Postgres.

Comment: Just use the absolute path for `pg_dump`.